# How to use COM .dll in C application?

Tags: c++, c, dll, com

I need to use the 32-bit COM dll *KCrypt.dll* in a C application.
It exposes an interface called *IKPassCrypt* that defines the two methods *Encrypt* and *Decrypt* as well as the implementation class *KPassCrypt*.

I've registered the dll using the command `regsvr32 KCrypt.dll` which a successful prompt. Then i tried to execute this block of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlcomcli.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#import "KCrypt.dll" raw_interfaces_only no_namespace

int main()
{

    HRESULT res = NULL;
    BSTR result = NULL;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    {
        HRESULT hr = NULL;
        
        GUID IID_IKPassCrypt;
        IIDFromString(L"{B4C89402-BF87-11D4-BA3E-00D0B7687982}", &IID_IKPassCrypt);

        GUID CLSID_KPassCrypt;
        CLSIDFromString(L"{B4C89403-BF87-11D4-BA3E-00D0B7687982}", &CLSID_KPassCrypt);

        

        IKPassCrypt* pC;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_KPassCrypt,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_IKPassCrypt,
            (void**)&pC
        );


        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::cout << GetLastError();
            throw _com_error(hr3);
        }

        BSTR text = SysAllocString(L"Hello");
        BSTR key = SysAllocString(L"Test");

        res = pC->Encrypt(text, key, &result);

        std::cout << res;

    }
    CoUninitialize();

}
```

However, the execution fails with an error 14007 ERROR_SXS_KEY_NOT_FOUND.

Analyzing with the Debugger, i realized that while the GUID of the Interface IKPassCrypt is correctly found, the same doesn't happen for the Class KPassCrypt. I'm providing the screen of the debugger before and after the execution of the CoCreateInstance line (I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022):

[Debugger variables before execution of CoCreateInstance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4nC2.png)

[Debugger variables after execution of CoCreateInstance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8SuE.png)

Could anyone help me with this issue and tell me what i'm doing wrong and how to make this work?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What I would try is to make a C++ dll using com and then give that wrapper dll an extern "C" interface and use that wrapper from "C". At least you get to use all the ATL support from C++. Have you looked for "C" libraries that can do the same (encryption) so you don't have to use COM at all?

Comment: Why do you explicitly mention KCrypt.dll is 32-bit? Does that mean your main project is 64-bit? Mixing bitness between main.exe and com.dll is not possible.

Comment: Bad error handling, use rand() to get a more predictable error code.  GetLastError() must only be used for failed winapi calls.  Display/diagnose the value of *hr* instead, fix the hr3 bug.

Comment: Use RegEdit to search the registry for `KCrypt.dll`, see what CLSID it's actually registered under.